# How can i upgrader cordova version to latest version on adf mobile 11.1.2.4

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

I develop on ADF Mobile 11.1.2.4. I think that 11.1.2.4 contains Cordova 2.2.0. What if upgrade to latest cordova version? What do i require to do?brgds

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in an easy standard way, but of course there is always way around.

Watch the below video about how to add a cordova plugin and use it in ADFM application, and it will give you a hint on how you can upgrade it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT4O4Wt9PXw

Note: be careful as any thing you'll do will disappear as soon as you download a new update of ADFM